# What does "file buffering" mean?

Tags: python, file, buffer

I'm very new to the world of programming and I'm trying to learn Python by myself because I read that is one of the best languages to start with. I'm using the book "Learn Python The Hard Way" and other internet researches and there's this word I've been having difficulty finding it's meaning: buffering.

I'll use a small phrase from the Python Documentation as an example:

> The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer
>   size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive
>   value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes). A
>   negative buffering means to use the system default, which is usually
>   line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If
>   omitted, the system default is used.

Comment: The Python chatroom has collected a [series of issues with LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints); I would not recommend the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. Shawn Mehan solved my problem.

Comment: Also, sorry if I messed up with anything. I'm new to the forum and trying to learn it's rules.